# why is there a buddhism meta forum?

Tags: discussion, support

i was on buddhism.stackexchange.com  and i clicked on the meta link and it brought me to buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com, but I was expecting to redirect to meta.stackexchange.com.  What is buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every StackExchange site has its own Meta site too.

Buddhism Meta SE is meant for Q&A on the operations and moderation of Buddhism SE.

So, if you have any technical questions (like "why have some of my points disappeared?"), questions on moderation decisions (like "why was this question of mine closed?"), suggestions for improvements of Buddhism SE (like "why don't we reorganize the tags in this way?") etc. you should discuss it here, on Buddhism Meta SE, and not Buddhism SE.

The moderators may also use Buddhism Meta SE to explain some policies.

Meta SE is like the meta for the whole platform, not just Buddhism SE. You can ask questions there like "why don't StackExchange introduce two factor authentication?"